# Why is my session not holding its data?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I've never run into this before but for some reason, when I am using AJAX to set a session variable, the session will not hold them.

Here is what I have:

```
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['selected'])){
      $_SESSION['user']['theme'] = array ('selected' => true);
    } // This should be now set with the value and it is for a time, but unsets

    if(isset($_POST['theme'])){
        $_SESSION['user']['theme'] = array('name' => $_POST['theme']);
    } // So should this
```

What I am seeing when I do a print_r under both `if` constructs is only the `$_SESSION['user']['theme']['name']` var and the other is not set. If I do a print_r just under the `selected` var, I can see it just fine. Somewhere, the key and value are disappearing for `selected`.

Why is this happening? I'm expecting to see both `name` and `selected`.

Comment: You're overriding the array each time? $_SESSION['user']['theme']['name'] = "whatever";

Comment: Yes, I suppose I am. How would I write this so that under user theme, I have both name and selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i said in my comment, you're overriding the array :)

```
session_start();
//changed it to unset if not in $_POST
$_SESSION['user']['theme']['selected'] = isset($_POST['selected']);


if(isset($_POST['theme'])){
       $_SESSION['user']['theme']['name'] = $_POST['theme'];
    } // and unset it too
else {
    $_SESSION['user']['theme']['name']= "";
}
```

Comment: Ok.. I initially wrote it like this but I was getting offset errors.

Comment: It will produce a warning because you're generating a key & variable at the same time, you can prefix the variable to suppress the warning when you are happy doing this. e.g.
    $_SESSION['user']['theme']['name'] = @$_POST['theme'];

Comment: Thanks. I really don't like suppressing the errors. How would I correctly write this so that it doesn't error?

Comment: Its a warning, not an error. Its designed to point out that you may have done something out of the ordinary. If this is exactly what you want to do its not a problem. you could generate the entire array at login with empty variables and assign the values when you want to or  store objects in the session array and have the properties or methods of those objects store and return the values :)

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for explaining. I did notice that if I check forst to see if it's been set then set it with an empty array, these notices don't appear. I've never ever had to do that before though which was what was making me crazy.

Comment: Yeah i know what you mean, session handling feels a bit like time travel sometimes! I've got to the point now where i use a lot of objects and use parameters so i can serialize or json chunks of them easily or do cool things like store the whole session in the database for later :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the `session` first

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['selected'])){
      $_SESSION['user']['theme'] = array ('selected' => true);
}
```

And also check whether the `$_POST` values are `not empty`.And you need to unset the name in session then assign it like

```
if(isset($_POST['theme'])){
    unset($_SESSION['user']['theme']['name']);

    $_SESSION['user']['theme'] = array('name' => $_POST['theme']);
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned it and have made the correction but it's already started.

Comment: And also check whether the $_POST values are not empty.

Comment: The issue here is that I'm overwriting my array. I need to rewrite it. I just have to figure out how.

Comment: The problem is in the assignment, you are still overwriting the `$_SESSION['user']['theme']` variable.

Comment: NO @jeroen he is assigning an array with the key of `name`.

Comment: Yes, thereby overwriting the value / unsetting the key of `$_SESSION['user']['theme']['selected']`.

Comment: The reason that I rewrote the code was because of the notices that were being thrown about illegal offset. I've never seen that before and quite honestly, I think I knew that I was probably overwriting the array.

Comment: That's why I suggested to unset the `name` value and then assign it not overwrite it

Comment: You are missing the point, `$_SESSION['user']['theme']` already is an array with a key - value pair with the key `selected`. Assigning a new array to `$_SESSION['user']['theme']` will overwrite the previous array value.

Comment: Thanks Gautam. I think I've got it now. It's weird because I've never seen that happen before.

Comment: @jeroen. Wait..... You know what I did? I'm so tired that I used the key name `theme` instead of name. I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of any page that sessions variables are accessed in any way, the first command must be a call to `session_start();`